# Ellipse to Standard Form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the equation to the ellipse, $9x^2+4y^2-72x+40y+208 = 0$, and I need it in standard form. I can't figure this one out.

Could this be the answer? $\frac{(x-4)^2}{9} + \frac{(y+5)^2}{4} = 1$

The other options are:

$\frac{(x-4)^2}{4} + \frac{(y-5)^2}{9} = 1$

$\frac{(x-4)^2}{4} + \frac{(y+5)^2}{9} = 1$

$(x-4)^2  + (y+5)^2 = 36$

Comment: Since this is multiple choice, you can (mentally) expand each of the "answers"  and see whether it matches the given equation. Very quick.

Comment: A quick way to narrow down the answer is look at the ratio of coefficients for $x^2$ vs $y^2$. It is $9 : 4 = \frac{1}{4} : \frac{1}{9}$. This means the solution is either the $2^{nd}$ or $3^{rd}$ one. Since they only differ in the sign for the square term containing $y$. One can look at the coefficient $y$ in original equation. Since it is positive, the correct solution is the $3^{rd}$ one: $$\frac{(x-4)^2}{4} + \frac{(y+5)^2}{9} = 1$$

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for that detailed response, buddy, you and everyone else who answered are the greatest.

Answer (score 1):

The following is correct.

$$\frac{(x-4)^2}{4} + \frac{(y+5)^2}{9}= 1$$

Answer (score 1):

its 2nd option

$\frac{(x-4)^2}{4} + \frac{(y+5)^2}{9} = 1$

Answer (score 0):

To convert a "general form" equation to "standard form", it will help to collect the "x-" and "y-terms", then factor out the quadratic coefficients before "completing the squares":

$$9x^2 \ -\ 72x \ + \ 4y^2 \ + \ 40y \ = \ -208  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 9 (x^2 \ -\ 8x) \ + \ 4( y^2 \ + \ 10y) \ = \ -208$$

$$\Rightarrow \ \ 9 (x^2 \ -\ 8x \ + \ 16) \ + \ 4( y^2 \ + \ 10y \ + 25 ) \ = \ -208 \ + \ 9 \cdot 16 \ + \ 4 \cdot 25  \ . $$

From there, you can set up the binomial squares in the "standard form" and divide through by the number on the right-hand side to find your result.